# Prevent routeparams from changing view when link is just "#"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using $routeParams with the following configuration:

```
controllersModule.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        }).
        when('/history', {
            templateUrl: 'views/history.html',
            controller: 'HistoryController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
    }
]);
```

Which works fine.

But in my page there are some links which have `href="#"`. When clicking these links i get a blank page.
Most of these links will go away while working on the project since they are just placeholders, but still i am curios if there's some way to prevent this from happening.
I have tried removing the href attribute from the "a" tags but this will remove the pointer on mouseover (i know i could just add a css rule) but i'd like a solution that i might put inside the routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `#` with `javascript:void(0);`

When a browser follows a javascript: URI, it evaluates the code in the
URI and then replaces the contents of the page with the returned
value, unless the returned value is `undefined` so you page remains same and do nothing.

Do nothing with `a` element

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
  Click here to do nothing
</a>
```

From MDN:

> Note, however, that the javascript: pseudo protocol is discouraged
>   over other alternatives, such as unobtrusive event handlers.

**Update:**

For `ng-href` if data comes from `$scope` with value `#` then simply replace `#` value with **empty string** so that page will not redirect to any page.

Inside controller:

```
this.mylink = this.mylink !== '#' ? this.mylink : '';
```

Comment: This would solve it for normal html links, the problem is that they won't work with ng-href as they will be considered unsafe by angular.

Comment: `ng-href` only required when you want to bind `$scope` value to `URL` which is not required in this case so no need to use `ng-href`

Comment: it is because, as i said in my question, some links URLs come from an object which is saved into the scope. It just happens that some URLs inside the object are "#"

Comment: I had already discovered that as i said in my question, and you need to put a css rule to add the pointer cursor for links without an href attribute. So i was hoping for a solution i could put inside the routing, but it looks like there's no alternative. Thanks